# Map more than 1 property of custom List object in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have below custom List object `List<Person> personList`

```
class Person(){
    String name;
    String age;
    String countryName;
    String stateName;
// getter and setter for all property
}
```

if i want to map `personList` based on countryName or StateName then i will do :

```
List<String> countryName = personList.stream().map(Person :: getCountryName)
```

or

```
List<String> stateName = personList.stream().map(Person :: getStateName)
```

But now i want to mapping personList based on CountryName and StateName in new custom List Object `List<Country> countryandStateList`

```
class Country(){
    String countryName;
    String stateName;
// getter and setter for CountryName and StateName
}
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong term. You are not filtering stream elements, you are mapping stream elements to elements of a different type.

Just `map` to `Country` instances:

```
List<Country> countries =
    personList.stream()
              .map(p->new Country(p.getCountry(),p.getState()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming the relevant constructor exists. If that's no the case, you can also use a parameter-less constructor and then call the setters on the created instance.

Comment: Will that not result in duplicate countries if several people come from duplicate sets of country-state?

Comment: @tucuxi yes it will. The OP didn't mention a requirement to avoid such duplicates. It can be easily done, though.

Comment: Thanks @Eran for quick answer. its working for me. I will remove duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

First filter as you did then create an object inside your map:

`List<Country> countryList = personList.stream().map(new Country(person.getCountryName(), person.getStateName()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
List<Country> countries = personList.stream()
            .map(person -> new Country(person.getCountryName(), 
                    person.getStateName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<Country> countries = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(person -> new 
                             Country(person.getCountryName(),
                    person.getStateName()), Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: what is the difference in both?

Comment: The first one uses intermediate map operation which is lazy and returns a stream of country and then collects into a list on collect operation.
The second one uses terminal collect operation directly which starts off the transformation, mapping each element to country and then passing it to another downstream collector to return a list.